# SSRS Deployed Report Not Executing WHERE clause

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report

I have an SSRS report that works perfectly in Visual Studio 2017.

But when I deploy it, the deployed report comes back with all the data, ignoring the filters in the `WHERE` clause. I know it's this because when I remove the `WHERE` clause from my Visual Studio report, the data matches the deployed report.

This report pings off a shared data source; the dataset is not a shared.

Even a simple `WHERE tbl.flag = 'Y'` does not seem to do anything to the deployed report.

*Why is SSRS not recognizing the entire SQL?*

Not really an expert in SSRS, I just make them based off some YT tutorials and deploy them to the link that was given to me, so any advice or links for research are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is actually updating the report on the server? If I had to guess, it seems like the report was originally deployed without a WHERE clause. Each time you have attempted to update it since has not actually updated the report on the server.

Comment: I don't think the server uses the saved physical file on the network, but stores it internally somewhere instead. So if you are just updating the physical file, I don't think that updates the stored copy it is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the issues was some inline comments I had in the SQL. I had some comments above the `WHERE` clause using dashes, `--`, explaining the filter. Once I removed it, the report executed correctly.

I was also able to change the comment style to the `/* <my comment> */` and it executed correctly. It seems that other style of comments with dashes made the server think everything afterwards was a comment, and therefore not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the server setting in the report project properties in Visual Studio.

If they look OK then delete the server copy of the report and redeploy.

If the report does not reappear then that proves that the report is either

a. not being deployed (you should see an error in the visual studio output window), or
b. it's being deployed to where you think it should be.

From the web portal you can search for a report by name and it will search all folders on the server so if it did deploy OK, you could find it that way.